Bearer token not included in request header
I tried using token based auth using Laravel Sanctum, using Nuxt JS on Front End

Laravel Framework 11.29.0 (http://192.168.10.11:8000)
Nuxt 3.13.2 running in (http://192.168.10.11:3000)

And installed this Module for authentication, with this settings in nuxt.config.ts
  sanctum: {
    mode: 'token',
    baseUrl: 'http://192.168.10.11:8000',
    origin: 'http://192.168.10.11:3000',
    endpoints: {
      login: '/api/login',
      logout: '/api/logout',
    },
    redirect: {
      onAuthOnly: '/login',
      onGuestOnly: '/pegawai'
    },
    globalMiddleware: {
      enabled: true,
    },
  }

its working normally using host http://localhost:3000, but when using local IP as host http://192.168.10.11:3000 and app try to access user api in http://192.168.10.11:8000/api/user, bearer token not included in request header and return {"message":"Unauthenticated."}
App Host http://localhost:3000 Request Header
GET /api/user HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en,id;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 192.168.10.11:8000
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
accept: application/json
authorization: Bearer 26|M50eSsFl35WVKA01GIedzPLRjye11ku8oqSu85h47xxxxxxx

App Host http://192.168.10.11:3000 Request Header
GET /api/user HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en,id;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 192.168.10.11:8000
Origin: http://192.168.10.11:3000
Referer: http://192.168.10.11:3000/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
accept: application/json

I've searched for a fix online, but haven't found a solution yet.
Thanks in Advance.
UPDATE CORS
I did already setup CORS settings.
// config/cors.php
'allowed_origins' => [env('FRONTEND_URL', 'http://localhost:3000')],

// .env
FRONTEND_URL=http://192.168.10.11:3000

Laravel already accepted login request in http://192.168.10.11:8000/api/login

UPDATE LOGIN LOGIC
I use this Module for auth sanctum logic in nuxt 3
const { login } = useSanctumAuth();

const userCredentials = {
  email: form.email,
  password: form.password,
  remember: form.remember,
};

await login(userCredentials);


share the code in nuxt that builds the header.

i used a module, the logic happen under the module

The issue might be related to CORS configuration when using an IP-based host instead of localhost. Laravel could be blocking the request due to incorrect CORS settings.
In your config/sanctum.php file. add your IP to the stateful key.
'stateful' => ['localhost', '192.168.10.11', '192.168.10.11:3000']

Go to your config/cors.php file, update the allowed origin to include the IP-based origin.
'allowed_origins' => ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://192.168.10.11:3000']


I did already setup CORS settings, Laravel did success response my login request, but get user request return 401 error, see updated questions, Thanks
